# Rails 3 - How to make entire table row clickable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a private messaging system that displays an "inbox" view of all received messages.  This view is simply generated from multiple table rows created by using a block in the view.

I would like to make each table row "clickable" and also pass a parameter (just as if I was using a standard link_to).  However, as you may know, you cannot make a tr clickable like you can with a div.

Therefore, I believe the solution will require some simple jQuery.  I have found some partial answers to this question, but not a complete one.

I know the code below is NOT correct (the link_to part), but can someone please show me how to hook up a rails link_to link using a jQuery click function?

Thanks!

```
$('tr').click(function() {
  <%= link_to :controller => "messages", :action => "show", :id => msg.convo_id %>
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/ and it seems to work perfectly (note:  'conver' is the class name of each table row).

```
$('.conver').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) {
    window.location = href;
  }
});  // end
```

Additionally, my "inbox" view has checkboxes in each row that I use to select a particular message and fire certain options such as save, delete, etc.  I needed to be able to check these checkboxes WITHOUT firing the link to the message.  Therefore, I added the following code:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
 });  // end
```

Hope this helps anyone trying to generate these same features that are common to most messaging systems.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {        
    $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
      window.location = this.dataset.link
    });
 });
</script>
```

Add link to view file:

```
<tr data-link="<%= edit_coaches_payment_path(payment) %>"> <td>#content Here</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to above, you may want to do something that allows for the addition and removal of rows without breaking the event if you are using lots of ajax calls.  You can instead bind the event to the table object for both items.

```
$("table.conver-table").on("click", "tr", function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) {
    window.location = href;
  }
});  // end

$("table.conver-table").on('click', ':checkbox', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
 });  // end
```