# Clickable Table Rows in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Just getting started with Rails and I am trying to create clickable table rows in Rails using bootstrap tables. I have managed to do this, however there seems to be a problem where when I click on the row through to the show page, then press the back button on that page to return to the index view, the clickable rows do not work anymore. I need to refresh the page to get it to work again.

I have taken a look at [Rails 3 - How to make entire table row clickable using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036251/rails-3-how-to-make-entire-table-row-clickable-using-jquery) along with other answers on the site. Still does not seem to work.

My code is as follows

Index Page

```
<tr data-link="<%= source_path(source) %>">
        <td><%= source.name %></td>
        <td><%= source.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to truncate(source.url, :length => 40), source.url, :target => '_blank' %></td>
        <td><%= source.category %></td>
        <td><%= source.user.name if source.user %></td>
      </tr>
```

application.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
window.location = this.dataset.link
});
})
```

Comment: This is because you define the event listener in a-way-i-cant-find-the-name but you should define it in a `$(document).ready(function(){#your_js_goes_here#})`

Comment: @MrYoshiji `jQuery(function($) {` is the same thing as `$(document).ready(function(){`. Just a shorthand version. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I am not sure about it @charlietfl, I can't find any source that confirm that

Comment: @MrYoshiji look at the docs I just linked...see `Which is equivalent to calling`

Comment: Yes, `jQuery(document).ready`, but not the OP's `jQuery(function($){#...})`

Comment: Yes...is same thing and is shown in docs also ... example: http://jsfiddle.net/nz8ajtpq/

Comment: @MrYoshiji will see it mostly as `$(function(){  });` and the extra `$` argument can be used if noConflict() was used to remove `$` alias

Comment: Okay after doing `jQuery(function($) { console.log(this) }` I can see that the event is triggered on `document`

Comment: @MrYoshiji  try `$=null` then use that ready and `$` will be jQuery inside  http://jsfiddle.net/nz8ajtpq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery `data()` method

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $("tr[data-link]").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data('link');
    });

});
```

I don;t know why yours isn't working. Perhaps you have errors thrown in browser console

Comment: Unfortunately still no joy, weirdly it works on my iphone as expected on the chrome browser, just not on any other browser I have. I have cleared the cache on all the browsers just to be sure and still no joy?

Comment: I removed all the data and started again and seems to work now... Weird behaviour...

Comment: It works, but it works once.  What i mean is that when i click, it follows the link, i hit the back link (in the page, not in the browser) and then it stops working.  No error thrown in the console.  --edit: it happens in ie, it happens in chrome, but not in the WebBrowser view i have in the desktop app that uses this functionality.

Comment: @h1k3n start a new question if you are having problems

Answer (score 2):

I like to leverage Stimulus for this type of problem.  Here's a simple stimulus controller I'm calling `nav_controller.js` that has a URL value and a method `goToUrl` that we'll call with a click action.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    url: String
  }

  goToUrl(){
    // Rails 7
    Turbo.visit(this.urlValue)
    // Prior to Rails 7 I would use the following
    // Turbolinks.visit(this.urlValue)
  }
}
```

To use this on any element we can set it up as follows. This example is used on a table row as we iterate over a collection of items.

```
<tbody>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr data-controller="nav" 
        data-nav-url-value="<%= item_path(item) %>"
        data-action="click->nav#goToUrl"
        style="cursor:pointer">
      <td><%= item.id %></td>
      <td><%= item.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.description %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps anyway else faced with this kind of issue in their ui. I used this in all of my Rails projects now for allowing users to just click on an entire row vs using a single clickable element.

Comment: Yeah this is a great example.